# TabBar исчезает при переходе на другой ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

В контроллере проверяется содержит ли корзина товары. Если имеет, то открывается контроллер с СollectionView, но при переходе исчезает TabBar. В чем проблема?

import UIKit

class EmptyCartViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

```
let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") ?? ""
let cart_id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "cart_id") ?? ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(cart_id.count)

    if cart_id.count != 0 {
        print("OK")
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotEmptyCart") as! NotEmptyCartViewController



        self.view.insertSubview(vc.view, belowSubview: tabBarController!.tabBar)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно так переходить на другие вью контроллеры. Используйте `NavigationController` или открывайте окно модально. При использовании `NavigationController` поставьте флаг `vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false` (по-моему, по умолчанию он и так false)

Answer (score 0):

У вас не правильно " построен переход"
Попробуйте так:

```
var window:UIWindow?
     self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    let homeController: UIViewController


    if ("Ваше условие") {

        homeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarControllerid") as! UITabBarController // create instance of HomeController or from Storyboard
    window?.rootViewController = homeController // change rootViewController to HomeController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible() // show window

}
```